# Opengl glBindTexture Using Last Texture Loaded

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

opengl uses only the last texture loaded and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
GLuint loadTex(const char* c) {
GLuint temp = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
    c,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );

if (0 == temp)
{
    printf("SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result());
    //return 0;
}

//glGenTextures(1, &temp);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, temp);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
return temp;
```

}

```
void drawObject(std::vector<Level::Triangle> faces, GLuint &resID, double x, double y, double z ){
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

//glColor3f(0, 1, 0);

glTranslatef(x, y, z);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, resID);
//glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
    Level::Triangle t = faces[i];

    glTexCoord2f(t.p1.tx, t.p1.ty);

    //glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);

    glVertex3f(t.p1.x, t.p1.y, t.p1.z);

    glTexCoord2f(t.p2.tx, t.p2.ty);

    //glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);

    glVertex3f(t.p2.x, t.p2.y, t.p2.z);

    glTexCoord2f(t.p3.tx, t.p3.ty);

    //glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);

    glVertex3f(t.p3.x, t.p3.y, t.p3.z);
}
glEnd();

glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
```

}

The textures are loaded into a c++ vector class array and then passed to the drawObject function. Only the last texture loaded is used when drawing objects, I'm not sure why. And yes, each time SOIL loads a texture it is assigned a new GLuint, and yes the textures are loaded prior to use.

Answer (score 4):

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, resID);
//glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
```

The only functions you can call in between `glBegin` and `glEnd` are vertex submission calls, like `glColor*`, `glTexCoord*`, `glVertex*`, and a few others. `glBindTexture` and `glActiveTexture` must be called *before* `glBegin`.

Also, you have the order of `glActiveTexture` and `glBindTexture` incorrect; you need to select the texture you want to bind to with `glActiveTexture` first, then actually bind it with `glBindTexture`.

(I also suggest you don't use `glBegin` and friends at all; learn to use vertex buffer objects, vertex array objects, and shaders, as `glBegin`, et.al. are deprecated and don't scale)

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe I didn't notice that